# Is it correct to store a reference of the Model object in a UITableViewCell that represents in it?

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, mvvm, mvp

I would like to know if it is "correct" to store a reference to the Model that a `UITableViewCell` represents in it.

The reason I ask is due to the necessity of knowing the Model in case of a click action in a button inside it.

Is there a better (a.k.a: desirable) way of doing this?

Example:

```
class Person {
    var name: String
    var lastName: String
    var age: Int
}

protocol PersonCellDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    // should the second parameter be the model that the cell represents?
    func songCell(_ cell: PersonCell, didClickAtEditButtonOfPerson person: Person)
}

class PersonCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet private weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private weak var lastNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private weak var ageLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet private weak var editButton: UIButton!

    // does the cell need to store its reference?
    var person: Person! {
        didSet {
            nameLabel.text = person.name
            // ...
        }
    }

    weak var delegate: PersonCellDelegate?

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table view cell is a view. Less it knows about the application logic, better it is.

You could retrieve the entity used using the `indexPath(for:)` method :

```
protocol MyTableViewCellDelegate: AnyObject {
    func myTableViewCellDidSomething(_ cell: MyTableViewCell)
}

class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    weak var delegate: MyTableViewCellDelegate?
}

class ViewController: UITableViewController, MyTableViewCellDelegate {

    var personList: [Person] = []

    func myTableViewCellDidSomething(_ cell: MyTableViewCell) {
        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }
        let person = personList[indexPath.row]
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You ask:

> does the cell need to store its reference?

No. In fact, that locks you into reference semantics and you might consider value semantics for the `Person` object. I also think it muddies the ownership model. Who now owns this `Person` object?

And even if you were committed to reference semantics, and wanted to use this pattern to detect `Person` changes, be wary that your `didSet` pattern is only half of the solution. The `Person` type is mutable and you’re detecting when the object is replaced with a new `Person` object, but not when the individual properties of `Person` change. If you’re going to go down this `didSet` road with mutable reference types, you might also want to add KVO for the relevant properties, too.

This pattern entails a fairly tight coupling of view objects and model objects. As others have suggested, you might consider other patterns for addressing this and/or reducing the burden on the view controller.

If you’re looking for automatic updating of the cell when the `Person` object mutates (and potentially vice versa), you can consider binding patterns, such as offered by libraries like [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift), [Bond](https://github.com/DeclarativeHub/Bond), etc.

I’d also refer you to Dave Delong’s presentation [A Better MVC](https://youtu.be/YWVzCd5FYbs), which walks you through considerations if you don’t want to give up on MVC, but figure out ways to work with it, or Medium’s [iOS Architecture Patterns](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-architecture-patterns-ecba4c38de52), which is an introduction to other options.

Answer (score 0):

In strict MVC, view should not access model directly.

When the user click the button in the cell, call delegate method. Let the delegate (usually is view controller) handle the click event (like modify model).

After updating the model, controller will update the view if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I do use it in some cases, especially as you do here, in a custom cell.
I don't rely on the UItableViewCell to hold the data for me, that I have in the model, as the cell can be reused, when it is off screen

Answer (score 0):

So, there isn't one right way, so I can just tell you would I would do.

If I didn't move cells, I would keep having model property. In cell class you shouldn't set properties of outlets, since cells are reusable. You just let controller know that data source is changed and you should reload rows/certain row.

```
var person: Person! // instead, tell controller, that person has been changed
```

Next, I would left delegate pattern and I would use closure variables. It makes code more Swifty (in future you can search for RxSwift).

```
class PersonCell: UITableViewCell {

    var personChanged: (Person) -> Void = { _ in }

    var person: Person!

    func foo() {
        // change person's properties
        personChanged(person)
    }

    func setCell() {
        nameLabel.text = person.name
    }



}
```

Then set all the things such as label's `text` in `cellForRowAt` `UITableViewDelegate`'s method. Also don't forget to set cell's closure and declare what should happen after person is changed

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = // ...
    cell.person = people[indexPath.row]
    cell.setCell()
    cell.personChanged = { [weak self] person in 
        guard let self = self else { return }
        self.people[indexPath.row] = person
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Basically this is correct but it fails if cells are moved around in the table view because the captured index path in the closure won't change.

Answer (score 0):

It depends:

If you can **move** cells in the table view (manually or by pressing a button) using `insertRows` and `deleteRows` then it's almost the only way (along with protocol/delegate) to be able to get the index path of a cell efficiently **without** reloading the entire table view.

In a straight table view where no cells are moved don't pass the model to the cell. You can use callback closures which capture the index path and even the model item.